# Bonjour ! Can you please explain to me the difference between gérondif passé and participe passé composé ?

Tags: grammaire, verbes

I can't understand the difference between them. I know how to form it, but I don't know when to use 'en' or not. For example: '*en ayant fait*' or '*ayant fait*'.

Merci!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ayant fait* translates easily to "having done" or "who had done".

> La date limite avait été rapportée, mais Pierre, ayant déjà rendu le devoir, n'en a tiré aucun profit.

*en* plus a participle translates most often to "by" or "while".

> Il a gagné du temps en sautant son petit déjeuner, bien qu'il le regrettait plus tard.

> Je fais mes devoirs et je prépare mon dîner tout en regardant le nouvel épisode de *C'est mon choix*.

It's hard for me to think of a situation where this would make sense in the past tense without it sounding awkward. "He saved time by *having* made his lunch the day before..." It could be reduced to just "by making", and likewise in French.